# NGINX: how to process requests with different http methods to one location differently

Tags: nginx, http-method

(The situation that caused the question is pretty defined and not abstract. But I know applicable to it workarounds thus I dropped details in order to get general pipeline that answers to this question.)

Problem description: Imagine that you have one `location` NGINX block and you want to have possibility to response in this block in different ways depending on requests' HTTP method. But NGINX does not support syntax like `location /:POST {...}`, some more complex way is needed.

I tried to find the answer to this question and all my findings can be classificated into these groups:

#### Group 1: `if ($request_method ...)` inside `location`

But [If is Evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) .

As for me, the pure `if` way does not work without copying directives into `if` clause from external "common" space. Moreover, all copied directives are not approved to be inside by NGINX's developers.

Only `return` and `rewrite` is approved to be inside `if` but it is not enough.

#### Group 2: `limit_except`

This way is applicable if you want to restrict some methods for a location. But it does not allow distinguishing behavior for each HTTP method group for the same location.

#### Group 3: lets `map` everything

Many `if` cases can be replaced by one/two/... proper `map` block(s). $request_method can also be mapped but what if it is not enough or pretty just `map` several times? How, for example, to `proxy_pass` requests with one HTTP method and perform `try_files` for requests with the same location and another HTTP method without `if`? (Not my situation, just example of two incompatible directives not allowed in `if`). How to avoid 10+ `map`s that can be needed for even one conditioning.

#### Group 4: proxying to different `upstream` blocks

This way is quite complex and looks like a overkill. Moreover, if you need something else than just proxying (for endpoint selection `map` is enough) you have to create a new virtual host. Also pieces of the implementation are located far apart.

Comment: I don't see a main question in the text. I don't understand. Can you please elaborte on the question in the title?

Comment: @qräbnö I added the description. Does it fulfil your request?

Comment: This is the problem I faced in [Nginx fully open cors with basic authentication without if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72158566/nginx-fully-open-cors-with-basic-authentication-without-if) and solved it, too.

Answer (score 2):

While I was writing the question I came up with the idea of error pages and named locations. However, the question has been submitted as a possibility to gather more solutions+opinions and help somebody.

#### Own idea 1: Error pages and named locations

`return` allows returning a error code without explicit redirection. But with providing a non-standard error code own error handler that just extend the functionality can be defined.

*Sometimes ago I found this technique as a solution of the "duplicated in-`location` directives" problem (the directives were placed at the error handler and the locations return the error code of the handler in addition to different directives of the locations).*

Usage example:

```
map $request_method $handler_code {
    GET 598;
    POST 599;
    default 405;  # Method Not Allowed
}

server {
    ...
    error_page 598 = @get_handler;
    location @get_handler {
        # only GET routine
    }
    error_page 599 = @post_handler;
    location @post_handler {
        # only POST routine
    }

    location / {
        ... # Common routine
        return $handler_code;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: `nginx: [emerg] invalid return code "$handler_code" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf:17`

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. It looks like NGINX was thinking that `$handler_code` is a string. Basing on this, I recommend check the following: 1) Do not put quotes around `$handler_code` ; 2) Check that `$handler_code` is written correctly in the `map` definition and that this `map` definition is located higher than `$handler_code` call.