# Nginx fully open cors with basic authentication without if

Tags: nginx, cors

This came up from time here and there but no question properly covers this use case.

The relevant section of `http`:

```
    map $http_origin $origin_with_default {
        default '*';
        ~. $http_origin;
    }
    map $request_method $es_target {
        default '';
        POST 'search';
        GET 'search';
        HEAD 'search';
        OPTIONS 'options';
    }
    root         /app;
```

The relevant section of `server`:

```
server {
  location ~* /(.*)/_search {
    limit_except OPTIONS {
      auth_basic "Read Users";
      auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd_read;
    }
    rewrite ^ /internal/$es_target;
  }
  location /internal {
    return 405;
  }
  location /internal/search/ {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://elasticsearch/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
    proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";

    proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
    proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials;
    proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers;
    proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials;

    include "cors.headers";
  }
  location /internal/options {
    internal;
    add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
    add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
    include "cors.headers";
    return 204;
  }
}
```

Finally, the `cors.headers` file:

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true" always;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $origin_with_default always;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
```

1. `POST https://example.com/index_name/_search` gives 401. This is as expected.
2. `OPTIONS https://example.com/index_name/_search` returns the options headers. This is also as expected.
3. However, `POST https://u:p@example.com/index_name/_search` gives a 404 and the server log contains `open() "/app/index_name/_search" failed (2: No such file or directory),`. Before I added the `rewrite ^ /internal/$es_target;` and the `location /internal/search/` section, when the `proxy_pass` was just after `limit_except` inside `location ~* /(.*)/_search {` it did work. Because of 1) and 2) I believe the rewrite and the location matching works. But why does it try to serve a file instead of doing a proxy pass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following answer will require the minimal understanding of two nginx base concepts - the request processing phases (described in the [development guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#http_phases)) and the location content handler (which can be either local, when the request is served using some local file contents, or not, when the response is coming from some kind of upstream - an HTTP proxy, FastCGI or uWSGI daemon, etc.).

Despite the fact that I have quite extensive experience in configuring nginx, `limit_except` isn't a directive I'd used to use frequently. To understand its behavior I did a couple of tests. Here is the list of nginx directives I'm going to use and the request processing phases where they are registering their handlers, in order of execution:

- `rewrite` - `NGX_HTTP_REWRITE_PHASE`
- `auth_basic` - `NGX_HTTP_ACCESS_PHASE`
- `try_files` - `NGX_HTTP_PRECONTENT_PHASE`
- `proxy_pass` - `NGX_HTTP_CONTENT_PHASE`

From all the above directives only `auth_basic` and `proxy_pass` are allowed to use inside the `limit_except` block. The `try_files "" <location>` trick I'm going to use described in [this](https://serverfault.com/a/1100562/498657) answer at ServerFault, so I would skip its detailed description here.

**TL;DR** The solution will be provided at the next part of the answer; the `limit_except` directive cannot be used to solve the problem.

---

## The `limit_except` directive behavior analysis

I will use the following config to analyze the `limit_except` directive behavior:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    return 200 "upstream: request URI is \"$request_uri\", request method is $request_method";
}
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;
    ... locations will vary during the tests
}
```

Under the `/var/www/html` directory I'll place a single `index.html` file with the single text line `index`.

Here we go.

```
location / {
    limit_except GET {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

```
> curl http://127.0.0.1/
index
> curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1/
upstream: request URI is "/", request method is POST
```

For the `GET` request nginx uses the local content handler. For the `POST` request nginx uses the `http_proxy_module` content handler.

```
location / {
    limit_except GET {}
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

```
> curl http://127.0.0.1/
upstream: request URI is "/", request method is GET
> curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1/
upstream: request URI is "/", request method is POST
```

Here nginx uses the defined `http_proxy_module` content handler for both requests. We didn't find anything we can't be expect yet. Lets go further.

```
location / {
    rewrite ^ /internal;
    limit_except GET {}
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
location /internal {
    return 200 internal;
}
```

```
> curl http://127.0.0.1/
internal
> curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1/
upstream: request URI is "/", request method is POST
```

The `rewrite` rules are completely ignored if the request falls under the `limit_except` condition. This looks like something we did not expect. However a quick search gives us the nginx trac [ticket](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/2323) referring the [following](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1383#comment:1) comment:

> The problem that rewrite module directives (`set`, `if`) are not inherited into the `limit_except` block, and not executed there.
> ...
> This behaviour is basically identical to a nested `location` block.

Now let's check the `try_files` directive behavior. To do it we will add the following `map` block

```
map $request_method $loc_name {
    POST    pst;
    default def;
}
```

and two named locations

```
location @def { return 200 def; }
location @pst { return 200 pst; }
```

to our configuration.

```
location / {
    try_files "" @$loc_name;
}
```

```
> curl http://127.0.0.1/
def
> curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1/
pst
```

The unconditional jump to the named location works as expected.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    try_files "" @$loc_name;
}
```

```
> curl http://127.0.0.1/
def
> curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1/
pst
```

This is also expected, since the `NGX_HTTP_PRECONTENT_PHASE` where `try_files` attaches its handler is executed before the `NGX_HTTP_CONTENT_PHASE` one.

```
location / {
    limit_except GET {}
    try_files "" @$loc_name;
}
```

```
> curl http://127.0.0.1/
def
> curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1/
(HTTP 405 Not Allowed)
```

Looks like the nginx tries to use local content handler for the `POST` request.

```
location / {
    limit_except GET {}
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    try_files "" @$loc_name;
}
```

```
> curl http://127.0.0.1/
def
> curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1/
upstream: request URI is "/", request method is POST
```

Bad news. The `NGX_HTTP_PRECONTENT_PHASE` handler defined in the main location did not get executed if the request falls under the `limit_except` condition. This looks similar to the nested locations behavior, although in contradistinction to the nested location we can't use the `try_files` directive inside the `limit_except` block.

Looks like the `limit_except` directive has some kind of limited use cases. Does it mean the question problem is not solvable? No. It means the `limit_except` directive cannot be used to solve it and we need to find some other way. Never give up :)

---

## Solution

You can optionally enable/disable basic authentication using the technique I just described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72182447/7121513). Add the additional `map` block to your configuration:

```
map $es_target $realm {
    search    "Read Users";
    default   off;
}
```

Now you can enable conditional basic auth in a following way:

```
location ~ /_search$ {
    auth_basic $realm;
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd_read;
}
```

However you can't use the `rewrite` directive in this block since that directive is executed during the `NGX_HTTP_REWRITE_PHASE`, and `auth_basic` directive register its handler at the later `NGX_HTTP_ACCESS_PHASE`. While for the regular `allow`/`deny` directives there is a way to do all the checks using only the rewrite module directives (generic example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72173828/7121513)), there is no such a way for basic auth. Fortunately we still can use our `try_files` [trick](https://serverfault.com/a/1100562/498657) (which will be executed at the later `NGX_HTTP_PRECONTENT_PHASE`). If by chance you are using OpenResty bundle or lua-nginx-module, you have an additional options described in the aforementioned answer.

I can see you already faced the problems with the correct URI that should be passed to the upstream. Your original `proxy_pass http://elasticsearch/;` will pass the `/` for every request, and the `proxy_pass http://elasticsearch;` will pass the rewritten URI. While your original request URI is always available via the `$request_uri` variable (which does not get changed with the `rewrite` directive unlike the `$uri` one), and something like `proxy_pass http://elasticsearch$request_uri;` should work too, we will use the named locations (we are not limited to, but that way we should prevent any URI changes at all). Here is the whole solution (I slightly optimize your first `map` block to prevent (some kind of expensive) regex library call):

```
map $http_origin $origin_with_default {
    ''      '*';
    default $http_origin;
}
map $request_method $es_target {
    POST 'search';
    GET 'search';
    HEAD 'search';
    OPTIONS 'options';
    default 'wrong';
}
map $es_target $realm {
    search    "Read Users";
    default   off;
}
```

```
location ~ /_search$ {
    auth_basic $realm;
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd_read;
    try_files "" @$es_target;
}
location @search {
    proxy_pass http://elasticsearch;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
    proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";

    proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
    proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials;
    proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers;
    proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials;

    include "cors.headers";
}
location @options {
    add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
    add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
    include "cors.headers";
    return 204;
}
location @wrong {
    return 405;
}
```

Comment: I _tried_ to find whether `try_files` accepts a variable or not but I was completely unable to. This is fantastic, I will test and if it works, I will move the accepted to this one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working config. It needed `limit_except` removed, every location switched to regex matching consuming everything -- and the last location being last is important to be so otherwise it gets into a rewrite loop. The "If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive" part of the rewrite module is not something I was able to get working.

We still need the `http` section:

```
    map $http_origin $origin_with_default {
        default '*';
        ~. $http_origin;
    }
    map $request_method $es_target {
        default 'invalid';
        POST 'search';
        GET 'search';
        HEAD 'search';
        OPTIONS 'options';
    }
```

And then comes `server`

```
server {
  location ~ /internal/search/(?<search>.*) {
    internal;
    auth_basic "Read Users";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd_read;
    proxy_pass http://elasticsearch/$search;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
    proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";

    proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
    proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials;
    proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers;
    proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials;

    include "cors.headers";
  }
  location ~ /internal/options {
    internal;
    add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
    add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
    include "cors.headers";
    return 204;
  }
  location ~ /internal/invalid {
    return 405;
  }
  location ~* /_search$ {
    rewrite (.*) /internal/$es_target$1;
  }
}
```