# Bypass basic auth with query parameter in Nginx

Tags: nginx

In my nginx configuration I have turned on basic auth to restrict access to the site like this:

```
auth_basic "Restricted Area";
auth_basic_user_file /path/to/htpasswd;
```

This works for users, but some tools we are using doesn't support basic auth so we need to use a query parameter instead of basic auth for these.

`auth_basic` can't be placed in an `if`-block so nginx won't accept this configuration:

```
if ($arg_auth_token = "my secret value") {
    auth_basic "Restricted Area";
    auth_basic_user_file /path/to/htpasswd;
}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is rather similar to the naive approach: use a variable and set it in the `if-block` instead.

```
set $auth "Restricted Area"; # Default to basic auth enabled

# Check the value of the auth_token query parameter
if ($arg_auth_token = "my secret value") {
    set $auth off; # Disable basic auth
}

auth_basic $auth; # This is now conditional based on the value of $arg_auth_token
auth_basic_user_file /path/to/htpasswd;
```

Answer (score 2):

The same can be achieved using the `map` block (which is better than using `if` in the `location` context):

```
map $arg_auth_token $realm {
    "my secret value"  off;
    default            "Restricted Area";
}
server {
    ...
    auth_basic $realm;
    auth_basic_user_file /path/to/htpasswd;
```

Caution! This trick cannot be used with any nginx directive, even if it accept the variables for its parameter. For example, trying to use this with the `access_log` directive won't give you some kind of conditional logging - it will create the log file named `off` instead.

Comment: Yeah, that would work too. My config is included inside the server block though so I'm not allowed to put a `map` block in there :/