# Logging issue with Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am using the following Nginx reverse proxy configuration.

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen      [::]:80;
    server_name www.test.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/www.test.com.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/www.test.com.error.log warn;

    location / {
        proxy_pass                         http://12.23.45.78:8080;
        proxy_http_version                 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection        "";
        proxy_set_header Host              $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    }
}
```

By adding the `access_log` and `error_log` parameters, it will log the access log.

Now I want to skip some logging, such as not logging `favicon.ico` and `apple-touch-icon.png`, so I added the following configuration.

```
location ~* ^/(?:favicon|apple-touch-icon) {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log    off;
}
```

But here is the problem, when I do this, `http://www.test.com/favicon.ico` will not be accessed properly, it prompts "`404 Not Found`" error.

It seems to indicate that the reverse proxy host is taking over the `favicon.ico` access without forwarding it to upstream for processing, is this normal Nginx behavior please?

If this is normal behavior, how should I set not to log for a given resource?

Any help is appreciated in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every request ends up in some location (if not being finished before). Every location uses its own *content handler*. Unless you specify something explicitly via content handler declaration directive (examples include, bit not limited to `proxy_pass`, `fastcgi_pass`, `uwsgi_pass`, etc.), it will be a **static** content handler to serve the requested content from local filesystem. Check my ServerFault answers ([1](https://serverfault.com/questions/1058098/a-location-for-static-content-without-listing-every-possible-extension/1100816#1100816), [2](https://serverfault.com/questions/1063505/extending-an-existing-location-configuration-instead-of-overwriting-it/1100820#1100820)) to find out some more details.

In some cases such a task can be solved using the `map` block, e.g.

```
map $uri $log {
    ~^/(?:favicon|apple-touch-icon)  off;
    default                          /var/log/nginx/access.log;
}
server {
    ...
    access_log  $log;
```

This approach can work when you need to implement lets say conditional basic auth ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72182447/7121513)). Unfortunately it **won't work** with the `access_log` directive - instead nginx will create the second log file named `off` for icon requests. So if you want every request to be passed to the `12.23.45.78` upstream, I don't see any other way but to duplicate content handler declaration for both locations. However every other used directive can be moved one level up, thus being inherited by both locations:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen      [::]:80;
    server_name www.test.com;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/www.test.com.error.log warn;

    proxy_http_version                 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection        "";
    proxy_set_header Host              $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    location / {
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/www.test.com.access.log;
        proxy_pass  http://12.23.45.78:8080;
    }
    location ~ ^/(?:fav|apple-touch-)icon {
        access_log  off;
        proxy_pass  http://12.23.45.78:8080;
    }
}
```

On the other hand, nothing can stop you from serving those two files locally and not passing those requests anywhere. Just put them into some dedicated directory and use a location with a static content handler:

```
location ~ ^/(?:fav|apple-touch-)icon {
    access_log  off;
    root  /full/path/to/folder/with/icons;
}
```